# Azure toolkit for eclipse throws error Missing requirement: Azure Common Plugin Library 2.9.5.201701250103

Tags: eclipse, azure

I have just installed the latest Eclipse IDE (same behavior with Indigo and Helios) and was installing Azure tools for Eclipse  via http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse. I am basically following the following article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation for this.

but the installation always fails with below error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Azure HDInsight plugin for Java 1.0.0.201701250103 (com.microsoft.hdinsights.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201701250103)
  Missing requirement: Azure Common Plugin Library 2.9.5.201701250103 (com.microsoftopentechnologies.wacommon 2.9.5.201701250103) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui 3.10.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: HDInsights 1.0.0.201701250103 (com.microsoft.hdinsights 1.0.0.201701250103)
    To: bundle com.microsoftopentechnologies.wacommon 2.9.5
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Azure HDInsight plugin for Java 1.0.0.201701250103 (com.microsoft.hdinsights.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201701250103)
To: com.microsoft.hdinsights [1.0.0.201701250103]
```

If I uncheck HDInsight from the installation, the error moves on to next items
like Azure WebApp Plugin for Java, Azure Explorer for Plugin etc.. and basically I cant install anything.

Appreciate any inputs to get this working.

Comment: I just installed Neon and that seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

not able to reproduce this issue. Pls make sure to try on a clean Eclipse install, and a recent version, like Mars or Neon.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question there is a missing plugin, check for that plugin in Eclipse market place. For me it gave error Missing requirement: Azure Core Plugin Library 3.31.0.202205311349 (com.microsoft.azuretools.core 3.31.0.202205311349). missing Mylyn plugin for which i downloaded Mylyn plugin first for Market place and then retried downloading Azure plugin

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32453251)

Answer (score 0):

First install Mylyn

[image: see this picture]

restart and then install Azure Toolkit